# Does Ruby 2.0.0 store error log files by default? If so, where are they?

Tags: ruby, logging, rubygems, installation

Where (if anywhere) does Ruby store error log messages/files relating to gem installs?

I have just installed Ruby 2.0.0 on a Windows 7 computer (my work computer, not my normal computer) and have been configuring it with a few gem installs.  When installing Mechanize, I received some error messages.  Regretfully, I did not think to save these error messages at the time, so now I want to find out exactly what they were.  My Mechanize gem works fine (at least on the surface) but I want to do some more digging to find out exactly what parts of the gem failed to install.

Having searched around on Google, I've mostly found info about gems for logging in Ruby, but nowhere have I found the default location for gem install error logs (or any logs).

I've also searched around the Ruby documentation and found the default "Logger" class.  There does not appear to be any information on specific paths to the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Guess not, as the [RubyGems API](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/) does not mention any class nor function that save the gems installation errors into log files. If your gem works fine, you could also try to check the errors all your gems could have by typping:

```
gem check --gems
```

This will check all your installed gems and report the errors it finds within them.